# How to get the operator from a BinaryExpression

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

I am trying to obtain the operator that is being used in a BinaryExpression. None of the public properties or methods are allowing me to do this. I have the following:

```
var binary = expr as BinaryExpression;
var operator = binary.Operator(); // of course this doesn't work
```

How do I do this?

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`NodeType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.nodetype.aspx). It's of type [`ExpressionType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx).

You can check if it's `ExpressionType.Add`, `ExpressionType.Subtract`, etc... or whatever operation you're looking for.